# h:selectManyCheckbox does not respect attribute "collectionType"

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra, selectmanycheckbox

several `h:selectManyCheckbox`s are backed by this map of type: `Map<Type, ArrayList<MyItem>>`.

The xhtml snippet looks like this:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox
    value="#{backingBean.values['type']}"
    collectionType="java.util.ArrayList"
    converter="#{myCustomConverter}>
    <f:selectItems .../>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

The checkboxes are display correctly, and the converter is used correctly in both ways.

Unfortunately when I try to access the values of the map after submitting the page, the map does not hold lists anymore. Instead I get a ClassCastException, because the values have been replaced by an `Object[]`.

Searching the internet, I seem to have exactly the same problem as in [MyFaces](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3522).

I think, I have tracked down the issue to `MenuRenderer`. The type of the EL expression is determined, which leads to Object in my case. But only if the type is related to `Collection` in the first place, the attribute `collectionType` is respected.

I use Mojarra 2.1.0, but even later versions did not change the relevant source code.

Summing up:

- Do I have the correct expectaction that the `List` shall remain a
  `List`?
- I this really a bug? If so, has it been fixed in later versions?
- Is there a workaround?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,

Daniel